# Java 8 : formatting Instant according to ISO 8601 with Zone-Offset

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, datetime-format, java-time

I'm trying to create the ISO 8601 formatted DateTime from the `Instant` object as per the reference in [*this article*](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) I used the format `YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss'T'ZD` to parse the Instant date as below.

But it's generating the time in wrong format:

```
2022-06-172T06:08:13T-0500172
```

The expected format should be:

```
2022-06-21T13:31:49-05:00
```

*My code:*

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss'T'ZD")
            .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

formatter.format(Instant.now())
```

How can I produce the formatted time as shown below?

```
2022-06-21T13:31:49-05:00
```

Comment: Check out the [`DateTimeFormatter` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to see what `Y`, `D` and `h` mean. In any case, it looks like you're looking for the default format used by `parse()` and `toString()`, so the custom formatter is unnecessary.

Comment: How far away are you with `System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now());` ?

Comment: @g00se Not exactly. Time representation will not match, and there would be a time-zone ID (which OP doesn't need) after the zone-offset.

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

> help with producing the time formatted as 2022-06-21T13:31:49-05:00

```
OffsetDateTime.now().toString()
```

> 2022-06-22T04:38:55.902569200+03:00

## ISO 8601

No need to define a formatting pattern.

Your desired output complies with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard of date-time formats. The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating text.

## `OffsetDateTime`

To represent a moment as seen in a particular [offset](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html), use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now() ;
```

Generate your text by calling `toString`.

```
String output = odt.toString() ;
```

> 2022-06-22T04:38:55.902569200+03:00

If you want to discard the fractional second, [truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)).

```
OffsetDateTime
.now()
.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS )
.toString()
```

> 2022-06-22T04:38:55+03:00

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I added a mention of truncation. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: Correct and immensely simple, no need to use pattern.

Comment: If the OP wants the UTC offset of a particular time zone, they may give that time zone as argument to `OffsetDateTime.now()`, for example `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Dawson"))`.

Answer (score 4):

I guess the pattern you need is `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssxxx"`

- `y` - year (*not `Y` - week-based-year*);
- `d` - day of the month (*not `D` - day of the year*);
- `x` - zone-offset (*not `ZD`*);
- There's no need in `T` in the end if you don't want it to be present in the formatted string.

Quote from the [*documentation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) regarding the zone-offset formatting:

> **Offset** `X` and `x`: This formats the offset based on the number of pattern
> letters. One letter outputs just the hour, such as '+01', unless the
> minute is non-zero in which case the minute is also output, such as
> '+0130'. Two letters outputs the hour and minute, without a colon,
> such as '+0130'. **Three letters** outputs the **hour** and **minute**, with a
> **colon**, such as `+01:30`.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssxxx")
    .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    
System.out.println(formatter.format(Instant.now()));
```

*Output:*

```
2022-06-22T03:05:43+03:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Its pretty close but the expected output should have a colon in the timezone `2022-06-22T02:41:51+03:00`

Comment: @OTUser I've managed to format the zone offset with a colon.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Lowercase `dd` instead of `DD` sets the pattern as you expect.  As @AlexanderIvanchenko said, the uppercase `D` represents day of the year`.  The lowercase `d` represents day of the month.  This should be the excepted answer.